# What is the simplest example of a non-exchangeable sequence of random variables?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I read the wiki article on exchangeability which contained examples, but not negative examples. Can you please provide the simplest negative example of exchangeable random variables?

Also, I know that:

$P(x_1, x_2) = P(x_1 | x_2) P(x_2) = P(x_2 | x_1) P(x_1)$

I thought this is always true, but now I think it is invalid for cases of non-exchangeable random variables, but I cannot see examples.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, let $X_1$ be a random variable that always equals $1$ and $X_2$ a random variable that always equals $2$; then $X_1,X_2$ forms a non-exchangeable pair.

Comment: @GregMartin those seem independent random vairables to me. Independent random variables are trivially exchangeable, am I right?

Comment: @JohnDeterious Independent *and identically distributed* random variables are exchangeable.

Comment: @grand_chat can you please show me how $p(x_1, x_2)$ is not the same as $p(x_2, x_1)$ for the example given by Greg ?

Comment: $P(X_1=1)=1$ but $P(X_2=1)=0$. Thus the pair $(X_1,X_2)$ doesn't have the same joint distribution as the exchanged pair $(X_2, X_1)$. The example cited by @GregMartin is pretty much the simplest example of not-exchangeable.

Comment: @grand_chat got it before you wrote the comment. Thank you all.

Comment: See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229528/which-probability-distributions-are-not-exchangeable

Comment: @Math1000 I read that question, it is not even asked properly. Thanks

Comment: @grand_chat can I make a blanket statement that any set of random variables that are independent but not identically distributed are non-exchangeable? and are there different sorts of examples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A list of variables, each with different marginal distributions, is an easy example of non-exchangeable, even if they're independent. Or a sequence where only one variable has a different distribution from the others.

But even variables that are identically distributed can be non-exchangeable. Example: Let the pair $(X_1,X_2)$ be uniformly distributed over the shaded 'pinwheel' region pictured below.
[image]

Then both $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same (uniform) marginal distribution, but they are not exchangeable. Suppose $X_1$ lives on the horizontal axis, and $X_2$ on the vertical, and the enclosing square runs from $(0,0)$ to $(2,2)$. Then $P(X_1\le X_2\le 1)= 1/4$ while $P(X_2\le X_1\le 1)=0$. For $(X_1,X_2)$ to be exchangeable we'd need the joint distribution to be symmetric: it would need to look the same when reflected across the diagonal line $x_2=x_1$.

For a discrete example of non-exchangeable but identically distributed random variables, let the pair $(X_1, X_2)$ take the three values $(0,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(2,0)$ with equal probability. Then both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are uniformly distributed on the set $\{0,1,2\}$. But $P(X_1<X_2) = 2/3$ while $P(X_2 < X_1) = 1/3$, hence $X_1$ and $X_2$ cannot be swapped. (This  construction can be generalized to create a list $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n$ of $n$ random variables  that are identically distributed but are not exchangeable: Place mass $1/n$ on the point $(0, 1, \ldots, n-1)$, "rotate" to create the next point $(1, 2,\ldots, n-1, 0)$, and repeat.)

Comment: and still whether it is exchaneable or not, $P(x_1, x_2) = P(x_1 | x_2) P(x_2) = P(x_2 | x_1) P(x_1)$
still applies, and is irrelavent, correct ?

Comment: Right, the formula $P(x_1,x_2)=P(x_1\mid x_2)P(x_2)$ is universally valid for all pairs of RVs -- it follows from the definition of conditional probability.